# How to include(attach) javascript to a certain PHP Control (Class)

Tags: php, javascript, class, controls

I'm writing php and I have a custom made control that is Grid and I would wanna know how to attach its javascript with it and everytime someone uses that control the javascript will be included automatically and if it's already included then it should not be included again.

For example I have the following page:

```
<html>
 <head>
  //Notice that nothing is included here
 </head>
 <body>
  <?php grid = new Grid() ?>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try to be more specified, this question is a little confusing

Comment: Well the Grid class has it's own javascript file (grid.js) and I want it to be included everytime the grid is used in a web page but just once at a page. There is a way of registering javascript and css files in ASP.NET so I thought that the same is possible here.

Comment: Here is one approach to bind them: http://agiletoolkit.org/learn/understand/chains/bind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want to attach a specific js file (in this case the grid.js) to your html file which in turn will be used by the php grid class.

```
<html>
   <head>
      <?php if(isset(loadgridjs)){ ?>
           <script type="text/javascript" src="grid.js"></script>
      <?php } ?>
   </head>
   <body>
      <?php grid = new Grid() ?>
   </body>
```

If loadgridjs has been set then it will include the grid.js to your html. There are other ways how to do this and I believe this is the simplest one

Comment: No I don't want to write anything in the head tag. Just when you create an instance of the Grid you get the javascript automatically inserted.

Comment: Do you have a constructor inside your class?  inside your constructor add this code:  echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="grid.js"></script>';